# Calculating timespan with t-sql

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Given two date/times:

```
@start_date = '2009-04-15 10:24:00.000'
@end_date = '2009-04-16 19:43:01.000'
```

Is it possible to calculate the time elapsed between the two dates in the following format

1d 9h 19m

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can [get the difference between the two dates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) to whatever resolution you want (in your example, minutes):

```
DATEDIFF(minute, @start_date, @end_date)
```

From there it's a simple matter of dividing minutes into hours and hours into days and modding the remainder.

Comment: I can see how DATEDIFF might work but it always returns TOTAL time. I can get total days or total hours but I can't get the span 1day 9hours. At least not in a straight forward way. Example?

Comment: @jdiaz as stated in the answer, you need to get the total at the level of precision you need. If you need precision to minutes then get it in minutes, then divide by 60 to get the hours (remainder is minutes), then divide the hours by 24 to get days (remainder is hours).

Comment: If you use DATEDIFF(second, @start_date, @end_date), this example http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/date-time-routines-manipulation/how-do-i-convert-a-timespan-in-seconds-to-hh-mm-ss.html willl get you started on how to convert seconds to HH:MM:SS.

Comment: @JJS The link is not valid anymore.

Comment: This should do the trick: SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(second, \@start_date, \@end_date) / 3600 AS varchar(max)) + ':'
 + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(second, \@start_date, \@end_date) % 3600 / 60 AS varchar(2)), 2) + ':'
 + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(second, \@start_date, \@end_date) % 60 AS varchar(2)), 2) - bah, does anybody know how to escape the at sign in comments?

Comment: @needfulthing use archive org - https://web.archive.org/web/20071211222018/http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/date-time-routines-manipulation/how-do-i-convert-a-timespan-in-seconds-to-hh-mm-ss.html

Answer (score 30):

I know this thread is older and the original participants are likely no longer watching, but I stumbled upon it, and had already written some code fairly recently to do something very close to what jdiaz is requesting. The result is rendered as a string in D:H:M:S format.

Step one would be to get the time span in seconds:

```
DECLARE @ElapsedS INT
SET @ElapsedS = DATEDIFF(second, @start_date, @end_date)
```

Now create the following scalar function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udfTimeSpanFromSeconds]
(
    @Seconds int
)
RETURNS varchar(15)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE 
    --Variable to hold our result
      @DHMS varchar(15)
    --Integers for doing the math
    , @Days int --Integer days
    , @Hours int --Integer hours
    , @Minutes int --Integer minutes
    --Strings for providing the display
    , @sDays varchar(5) --String days
    , @sHours varchar(2) --String hours
    , @sMinutes varchar(2) --String minutes
    , @sSeconds varchar(2) --String seconds

--Get the values using modulos where appropriate
SET @Hours = @Seconds/3600
SET @Minutes = (@Seconds % 3600) /60
SET @Seconds = (@Seconds % 3600) % 60

--If we have 24 or more hours, split the @Hours value into days and hours
IF @Hours > 23 
BEGIN
    SET @Days = @Hours/24
    SET @Hours = (@Hours % 24)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Days = 0
END

--Now render the whole thing as string values for display
SET @sDays = convert(varchar, @Days)
SET @sHours = RIGHT('0' + convert(varchar, @Hours), 2)
SET @sMinutes = RIGHT('0' + convert(varchar, @Minutes), 2)
SET @sSeconds = RIGHT('0' + convert(varchar, @Seconds), 2)

--Concatenate, concatenate, concatenate
SET @DHMS =  @sDays + ':' + @sHours + ':' + @sMinutes + ':' + @sSeconds

RETURN @DHMS

END
```

Now feed your timespan into the newly created function:

```
SELECT TimeSpan = dbo.udfTimeSpanFromSeconds(@ElapsedS)
```

Should produce '1:09:19:01'

Answer (score 24):

```
CONVERT(
  varchar(8),
  (
    CAST(@end_date AS DATETIME)
    -
    CAST(@start_date AS DATETIME)
  )
  ,108
)
```

This'll give it to you as HH:MM:SS

Cheers

Comment: By the way 108 refers to a style for convert as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

108 - hh:mi:ss

You might also try 114 to get milliseconds
114 - hh:mi:ss:mmm(24h)

Comment: Note: if the values are DATETIME2 instead of DATETIME, you'll need to convert them to do the subtraction. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63753337/352349

Comment: This should be the answer.. It's simple an it works. I will edit to add the datetime thing and also add a varchar size. Even though it works, it's a bad habit

Comment: Careful! This result throws away anything > 23 hours, 59 minutes, and 59.999 seconds. Using this with the OP input values gives you 9:19:01 and throws away the day.

Answer (score 4):

DATEDIFF can return unintuitive values. For example, the two dates below differ by one second yet DATEDIFF with the parameters below and interpreted as others have interpreted it above returns 1 year:

SELECT DATEDIFF(year, '2005-12-31 23:59:59', '2006-01-01 00:00:00')

Look at the MSDN documentation for DATEDIFF to understand how it works.

Comment: Well, if you define your precision as "year" then there's nothing unintuitive here. If you tell the database that you want second-precision, you should get your 1s.

Comment: "intuitive" is what *most reasonable people* would expect.  Imho, they (likely not having read the fine print in the docs) would expect the above to be 0 vs. 1.  If you've been alive for anywhere from, say, 1 nanosecond to 364 days, 23 hours, 59 minutes and 59 seconds old, how many "years" old are you?  0 not 1.  Even if you're allowing for rounding to nearest year, anything less than 7 months, should still round to 0 years old.  If you're speaking of "years *of age*" (i.e. for legal purposes) vs. "years *old*", then you definitely would *not* round (you would truncate aka round down).

Answer (score 1):

datediff(datepart, date1, date2);

Rex's answer is more complete.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you format the datediff (50d 8h 35m) in a query:

```
Declare @Date1 as Datetime, @Date2 as Datetime
Set @Date1 = '2005-01-01 08:00:00'
Set @Date2 = '2005-02-20 16:35:30'

Select
CAST(DATEDIFF(Minute,@Date1, @Date2)/60/24 as Varchar(50)) ++ 'd ' ++ 
CAST((DATEDIFF(Minute,@Date1, @Date2)/60)-((DATEDIFF(Minute,@Date1, @Date2)/60/24)*24) as Varchar(50)) ++ 'h ' ++
CAST((DATEDIFF(Minute,@Date1, @Date2)) - (DATEDIFF(HOUR,@Date1, @Date2)*60) as Varchar(50)) ++ 'm' as FormattedDateDiff
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @FirstDate DATETIME, @SecondDate DATETIME, @result VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @FirstDate = '2017-03-01 09:54:00.637', @SecondDate = GETDATE()

DECLARE @Day INT,@Month INT,@Hour INT, @Minute INT,@TotalSeconds INT,@Year INT
SELECT @TotalSeconds = ABS(DATEDIFF(SECOND,@FirstDate,@SecondDate))

-- Standard values in seconds
DECLARE @YearSeconds INT, @MonthSeconds INT, @DaySeconds INT, @HourSeconds INT, @MinuteSeconds INT

SELECT  @MinuteSeconds = 60
SELECT  @HourSeconds = 60 * @MinuteSeconds 
SELECT  @DaySeconds = 24 * @HourSeconds
SELECT  @MonthSeconds = 30 * @DaySeconds
SELECT  @YearSeconds = 12 * @MonthSeconds

--SELECT @MinuteSeconds AS [Minutes], @HourSeconds AS [Hours], @DaySeconds AS [Day],@MonthSeconds AS [Month],@YearSeconds AS [Year]

IF @TotalSeconds < @MinuteSeconds
BEGIN
    SELECT @result = CAST(@TotalSeconds AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ' seconds ago' 
END
ELSE IF @TotalSeconds < @HourSeconds
BEGIN
    SELECT @result = CAST(ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@FirstDate,@SecondDate)) AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ' minutes ago' 
END
ELSE IF @TotalSeconds < @DaySeconds
BEGIN
    SELECT @result = CAST(ABS(DATEDIFF(HOUR,@FirstDate,@SecondDate)) AS     NVARCHAR(20)) + ' hours ago' 
END
ELSE IF @TotalSeconds < @MonthSeconds
BEGIN
    SELECT @result = CAST(ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,@FirstDate,@SecondDate)) AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ' days ago' 
END
ELSE IF @TotalSeconds < @YearSeconds
BEGIN
    SELECT @result = CAST(ABS(DATEDIFF(MONTH,@FirstDate,@SecondDate)) AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ' months ago' 
END
ELSE IF @TotalSeconds > @YearSeconds
BEGIN
    SELECT @result = CAST(ABS(DATEDIFF(YEAR,@FirstDate,@SecondDate)) AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ' year ago' 
END


SELECT @result
```

Comment: Result Sample, "2 months ago" etc.