# Inserting custom query values from one into another, along with seperate corresponding field

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table timings with 4 different time fields namely : intime, outtime, lunchout, lunchin. I'm trying to find total hours logged i.e ((outtime-intime) - (lunchin-lunchout). Which I can fin out successfully using :

```
select convert (varchar(10),((outtime_d - intime_a)-(lunchin_c - lunchout_b)),8) as time1 from timings where fname = 'abc'

create table timings
(
fname varchar(max),
fid varchar(30) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
intime_a datetime,
outtime_d datetime,
lunchout_b datetime,
lunchin_c datetime
)

insert into timings values('Abc','4C00A2C82A0C','4/23/2012 2:07:51 PM','4/23/2012 9:07:51 PM','4/23/2012 4:12:51 PM','4/23/2012 5:07:51 PM')
time1 = 06:05:00
```

I have another table called attendance with the following fields : fname, presenttime, date.

```
create attendance timings
(
fname varchar(max),
presenttime datetime,
date datetime
)
```

I need to insert into attendance:

fname: fname from timings

presenttime: time1 - the result of above listed query

date: current system date. (only date, not time, need to remove timestamp from getdate() function)

I first attempted to use the datediff function, and late concatenate the values, but I was getting incorrect results.

```
SELECT ROUND(cast((datediff(hh, outtime_d ,intime_a) / 60.0) as FLOAT),2) AS DiffHour from timings where fname = 'abc'
SELECT ROUND(cast((datediff(mi, outtime_d ,intime_a) / 60.0) as FLOAT),2) AS DiffMinute from timings where fname = 'abc'
SELECT ROUND(cast((datediff(ss, outtime_d ,intime_a) / 60.0) as FLOAT),2) AS DiffSec from timings where fname = 'abc'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing both the field's datatypes to varchar

and used this:

```
insert into attendance(fname,presenttime,date)
SELECT 
fname, 
CAST(CONVERT (VARCHAR(10),((outtime_d - intime_a)-(lunchin_c - lunchout_b)),8) AS varchar(10)),
CONVERT (VARCHAR(10),getdate(),3)
FROM timings WHERE fname = 'abc'
```

The results are satisfactory for now.

Answer (score 0):

You are making it more complicated that it needs to be.  You don't have to convert or divide when you use DATEDIFF. Here is the link to see how [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) works.

Try using code something like this:

SELECT DATEDIFF(hh, outtime_d ,intime_a) AS DiffHour from timings where fname = 'abc'

SELECT DATEDIFF(mi, outtime_d ,intime_a) AS DiffMinute from timings where fname = 'abc'

SELECT DATEDIFF(ss, outtime_d ,intime_a) AS DiffSec from timings where fname = 'abc'

If you are trying to save the hours, minutes and seconds in the field presenttime it will not work.  If you are looking for one field that will contain the hour, minute and day data you should use a [TimeSpan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758891/calculating-timespan-with-t-sql) data type.

Comment: Yea, that is what I tried doing first, my datediff queries were giving me incorrect results, however your's work find, but then the problem arises about not having them in a single field.

Comment: Have you tried to look at the TimeSpan data type?  You will be able to  have hours, minutes and seconds in 1 field.