# MS sql query for finding difference between two times?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I have a database table called 'student_details'.It contains a coloumn -'token_timestamp'. I want to find out the difference between current time and this 'token_timestamp' .It shouldnt be greater than 80minutes. What should i written in 'where' condition? Please help

```
    SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("select student_id from student_details where  ??? ,con1);
```

Comment: your token_timestamp contains only time r it contains date and time both give example what it contain.

Comment: showing only current_time like 10.00 AM (i have inserted it using DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() )

Comment: DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() returns only date part....like this....4/26/2013..there no time. IF U ADD  THIS THIN IT GOES LIKE .4/26/2013 00:00:00:00 .check your db WHAT IS  STORED THERE

Comment: no it shows like 15:29:53

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577898/sql-time-difference-between-two-dates-result-in-hhmmss)

Comment: no it not duplicate bcz his column dosnt have date part....uit contains only time

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("select student_id from student_details where 
    DateDiff(minute,Cast(token_timestamp as smalldatetime),CAST(cast(GetDate() as time) as smalldatetime))>80"
    ,con1);
```