# Dynamic column in MySql showing Timedifference

Tags: mysql

I need a column in a MySql datatable which shows the difference between now and a timestamp. I have the following column within a view but I need a corresponding column in a datatable (InnoDB)

```
time_format(timediff(`myTable`.`anyTimestamp`, now()), '%H:%i')) AS `timeDifference`
```

I may also use a procedure but this one should be executed at least every 3 minutes and I wonder how this procedure would influence overall perfomance of the datatable since there are > 1000000 datasets stored in it.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a column, or do you in fact just need the time difference to be caluclated in your SQL statement.

See : [SQL time difference between two dates result in hh:mm:ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577898/sql-time-difference-between-two-dates-result-in-hhmmss)

Comment: I need a column. The code above shows how to get the difference in a statement.

Comment: In that case, I suspect you are going to take a substantial performance hit as that is a lot of work to be undertaken across all of the rows.
I would recommend only calculating it when required and only for the rows that required it - hence the SQL suggestion.