# How to substract varchar datatype time in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have two columns INTIME, OUTTIME as 09:03:01 as INTIME and 18:06:00 AS OUTTIME Datatype for these columns is varchar type now I want to calculate the duration between OUTTIME minus INTIME then I need to get duration as 9:02:59

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings - you're just asking for trouble that way. Use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL time difference between two dates result in hh:mm:ss](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577898/sql-time-difference-between-two-dates-result-in-hhmmss)

Answer (score 1):

Just substract them:

```
DECLARE @INTIME DATETIME, @OUTTIME DATETIME
SELECT @INTIME = CONVERT(DATETIME,'09:03:01'), @OUTTIME = CONVERT(DATETIME,'18:06:00')
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@OUTTIME - @INTIME,108)
```

Output: `09:02:59`

Answer (score 0):

try out this. may this will help you.

```
select CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(second,datediff(second, cast('09:03:01' as datetime),cast('18:06:00' as datetime)),0),108) as duration
```

Check out this online

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/19536)