# How to get seconds between two dates in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I had this MySQL code

```
DELETE FROM UserError WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) > 86400
```

What is equivalent of this MySQL code in SQL Server?

Comment: In MSSQL, you need to use DATEDIFF function. Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577898/sql-time-difference-between-two-dates-result-in-hhmmss

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use datediff

```
DELETE FROM UserError WHERE 
Datediff(s, [date], getdate()) > 86400
```

Comment: Plus one for the example that shows `GETDATE()` and not just `DATEDIFF`, which is part of what OP needs.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(second, '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000'); 

--Syntax
       DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of DateDiff for this. It looks like this:

```
DateDiff(datePart,startDate,endDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DATEDIFF ( ss , startdate , enddate )
```