# Calculate total time between two times in sql

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am using following sql to calculate time difference for records in a table and taking sum of them grouping by employeeId and login Date, But I am injecting a condition in the middle,If the LogOffTime is null I want to take the difference of current time of the day and the time employee loggedin.
Note : Each employee can have multiple Logins and LogOffs in a day

```
ROUND(SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, LogInTime,   IIF(LogOffTime <> NULL,LogOffTime,GetDate()))) / 3600.0, 1) as HoursWorked
```

But my condition `IIF(LogOffTime <> NULL,LogOffTime,GetDate())` seems incorrect here, Does somebody has any Idea, if the condition is correct.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577898/sql-time-difference-between-two-dates-result-in-hhmmss

Comment: @zedfoxus My question is different, sorry if I didn't presented well, but I got my result.

Comment: I haven't downvoted. I am unsure why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Reversed the condition and it worked, thanks, following is the sql

```
ROUND(SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, LogInTime, 
                    IIF(LogOffTime IS NULL,GetDate(),LogOffTime)
                    )) / 3600.0, 1) as SystemHours
```