# Search between two dates in database c#

Tags: c#

```
public void LoadAttendance()
{
    DataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM AttendanceDatabase where EmpName = '" + txtEmpName.Text + "'", con);
    DataTable = new DataTable();
    DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable);
    dgvAttendance.DataSource = DataTable;
    dgvAttendance.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "h:mm tt";
    dgvAttendance.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "h:mm tt";
}
```

I want to search a record in between two dates and Employee Name. Can someone help me about the query?
    public void FillPresentDays()
        {

```
      Public void FillPresentDays
      {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select COUNT(*) from AttendanceDatabase  WHERE EmpName =@EmpName and Date between @d1 and @d2", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", txtEmpName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", dtDate1.Value.Date);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", dtDate2.Value.Date);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        txtPdays.Text = count.ToString();
        con.Close();
        LoadAttendance();

    }
```

this code is working  the datetimepicker used here is the same that i will used in the LoadAttendance.

Comment: DataTable is Type and you are using like a Variable.

Comment: Can you show us your aspx coding? specially datetime picker format.

Comment: Can i copy here all of my code?

Comment: yup can but I want to see only your datetime picker.

Comment: my datetimepicker format is shortdate.

Comment: im noob in c# lol. i dont know where it is.

Comment: I already solved it sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void LoadAttendance()
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from AttendanceDatabase WHERE EmpName = @EmpName and Date between @d1 and @d2", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", txtEmpName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", dtDate1.Value.Date);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", dtDate2.Value.Date);
        DataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable = new DataTable();
        DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable);
        dgvAttendance.DataSource = DataTable;
        con.Close();
    }
```

here how i solved lol.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void LoadAttendance()
{
    DateTime fromdt = DateTime.ParseExact("1/1/2009", "M/d/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
    DateTime todt = DateTime.ParseExact("1/1/2010", "M/d/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
    DataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM AttendanceDatabase where EmpName = '" + txtEmpName.Text + "' AND (DateField BETWEEN '" + fromdt +"' AND '" + todt + "') ", con);
    DataTable = new DataTable();
    DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable);
    dgvAttendance.DataSource = DataTable;
    dgvAttendance.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "h:mm tt";
    dgvAttendance.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "h:mm tt";
}
```

Use your datetime format instead 'm/d/yyyy'.

If its not work. try

DateField >= @fromdt AND DateField < @todt

Comment: culture info cannot be found. how to fix this sir?

Comment: i have two datetime picker and i want to search a records by those two datetimepicker and employee name.

Comment: see updated answer. convert datetimepicker value as dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577898/sql-time-difference-between-two-dates-result-in-hhmmss

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM AttendanceDatabase 
WHERE EmpName = '" + txtEmpName.Text + "' 
AND 
(DateField BETWEEN '" + DateTime.Parse(StartDate) + "' 
    AND '" + DateTime.Parse(EndDate) + "')"
```

Comment: it gives me data type mismatch criteria exception