# How to display Hours and Minutes between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am having a table consists of to datetime columns "StartTime" and "CompleteTime". Initially completeTime column will be NULL untill the process is completed. And now my requirement is to display hours and minutes as shown Below

**Output:**
Ex: 2:01 Hr 
(This Means "2" represents hours and "01" represents minutes)

**I Tried as below:**

```
Declare @StartDate dateTime = '2016-03-31 04:59:11.253'
Declare @EndDate dateTime = GETUTCDATE()

SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(DATEDIFF(second, @StartDate, 
ISNULL(GETUTCDATE(),@EndDate)) / 36000.0 AS DECIMAL(9,2))) + ' hr','.',':')
```

**Output:**

```
0:05 hr
```

**Required Output:**

```
0:32 hr
```

**Note:** Hi while giving negative marking check my query once. I already referred some link's related to this but it won't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577898/sql-time-difference-between-two-dates-result-in-hhmmss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME = '2016-03-31 04:59:11.253'
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATETIME = GETUTCDATE()

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @STARTDATE, @ENDDATE)/60)+':'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @STARTDATE, @ENDDATE)%60)+' hr' AS DIFF
```

Result:

```
Diff
0:52 hr
```

Diff more than 24 hour also will handle this

```
72:56 hr
```

Answer (score 1):

try this (MS SQL query) -

```
Declare @StartDate dateTime = '2016-03-31 04:59:11.253'
Declare @EndDate dateTime = GETUTCDATE()

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(5), 
   DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, @StartDate, @EndDate), 0), 114) + ' hr'
```

Result - 00:47 hr

Comment: Diff more than 24 hour will not handle this

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @StartDate dateTime = '2016-03-31 04:59:11.253'

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, @StartDate,GETUTCDATE()), 0), 114) + ' Hr'
```

Returns: '0:43 Hr'

Your `ISNULL(GETUTCDATE(),@EndDate)` isn't doing anything since `GETUTCDATE()` will never be `NULL`, and you were dividing by `36000` instead of `3600`, but the primary issue with your query is that you were putting a decimal value into a sexagesimal container (60 minutes/hour). Ie: 90 seconds should be `1:30` instead of `:9`

Edit: Mixup in my initial query, the `DATEADD()` method is cleaner.