# Determining which Staff has been here longest

Tags: sql

So I have this table. How can I know which Staff has been here the longest?

```
create table Staff (
    StaffId     char(5) not null,
    StaffName   varchar(20) not null,
    StaffPhone  varchar(13),
    StaffIc     char(14),
    JoinDate    date,
    primary key(StaffId),
    constraint chk_StaffIc check (REGEXP_LIKE(StaffIc,'\d{6}\-\d{2}\-
    \d{4}')),
    constraint chk_StaffPhone check (REGEXP_LIKE(StaffPhone,'^01[0-9]-
    \d{7}|\d{8}$'))
);
```

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: The title and the text of the question makes no sense together. Dou you want to retrieve the staff that have been there the longest or create an object?

Comment: `select top 1 * from Staff order by JoinDate`?

Comment: Replying to Unlockedluca : I'm still trying to find how to compare the JoinDate of the staff and today's date as I'm still fresh to SQL.

Comment: Replying to litelite : Sorry I forgot to change the topic hahaha. I apologize for the mistake made.

Comment: you don't need to compare `JoinDate` to today's date, you only want the row with the "lowest" `JoinDate`.

Comment: What if I want to calculate how long has it been for the staff to work at the place?

Comment: see here for time between two dates: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577898/sql-time-difference-between-two-dates-result-in-hhmmss)

Comment: @JasonHew you should use an arobase when replying to people, it notifies them of your message, which they might otherwise miss.

Comment: What happens when one stuff is no longer stuff? delete? or add a field for endDate. Do you need to confirm is stuff is still stuff?

Comment: @Aaron I see. Thank you. Still exploring StackOverflow hahah

Comment: @Horaciux I'll delete

Answer (score 1):

For the longest, use `top 1` and order by`JoinDate` ascending. Shortest would be descending:

```
select      top 1
            StaffId,
            StaffName,
            StaffPhone,
            StaffIc,
            JoinDate,
from        Staff
order by    JoinDate asc
```

Answer (score 0):

This will tell you how long in days, it could also be month, years, etc.
 See [`DATEDIFF()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp)

```
select top 1 staffid, staffname, DATEDIFF(day,joindate,getdate()) from Staff
order by joindate
```

This use [`GETDATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql) to obtain current day