# How to find time difference in two times rows

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

SQL Server : I need to find difference between two times in the format of `HH:MM` and both columns having `time` datatype:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, sh.ToTime, sh.FromTime)
FROM ShiftTimes sh 
INNER JOIN StdBreaksInShifts sb ON sb.ShiftId = sh.ShiftId
```

Table:

```
Fromdate                todate
----------------------------------------
08:15:00.0000000        16:30:00.0000000
```

Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: Please add some sample data and add what you have tried so far.

Comment: Edit your question and add more details, maybe an example with some rows and which is the expected result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL time difference between two dates result in hh:mm:ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577898/sql-time-difference-between-two-dates-result-in-hhmmss)

Comment: Show sample of ToTime column data and FromTime column data. See Convert function from MSSQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CONVERT` with style to get part of the corresponding format. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @FromTime TIME = '08:15:00.0000000'
       ,@ToTime TIME = '16:30:00.0000000';

SELECT @FromTime
      ,@ToTime
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, @FromTime, @ToTime), 0), 114)
```

> 08:15:00.0000000  16:30:00.0000000    08:15

Comment: Thank you ... can you please tell me how i can implement this formula on generated difference =VALUE(K4)*60*24.