# Find duration in hh:mm:ss in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have starttime and endtime columns in my table and I want to get time difference between the two. But however I want the difference in hh:mm:ss format which I am not getting.

```
Declare @starttime = '7/23/2020 3:30:02 PM'
Declare @endtime = '7/23/2020 3:30:07 PM'
Select cast(@starttime - @endtime as Time) As Timedifference
```

I get 00:00:05.000000 which I don't want.

Comment: Then use a `time(0)` if you don't want nanoseconds...

Comment: you can convert the result into char(8) and it would strip the miliseconds.. Depends on what you do with the result afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```sql
select convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)/3600)+':'
      +convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)%3600/60)+':'
      +convert(varchar(5),(DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)%60)) as [hh:mm:ss]
```

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Server 2012 you can use `FORMAT` function.

In the following post you can find many solutions of this:

[SQL time difference between two dates result in hh:mm:ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577898/sql-time-difference-between-two-dates-result-in-hhmmss)

Below the best solution if you have SQL Server 2012 or later version:

```
--get the difference between two datetimes in the format: 'hh:mm:ss'
CREATE FUNCTION getDateDiff(@startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME)
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS BEGIN
  DECLARE @seconds INT = DATEDIFF(s, @startDate, @endDate)
  DECLARE @difference VARCHAR(10) =
  FORMAT(@seconds / 3600, '00') + ':' +
  FORMAT(@seconds % 3600 / 60, '00') + ':' +
  FORMAT(@seconds % 60, '00')
  RETURN @difference
END
```

For `FORMAT` documentation look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)