# How can I write this function to calculate datetime diff as hh:mm:ss:ms

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, dmv

I am not a developer so please pardon my question. I am more of prod DBA

We have an SSRS page which displays the long running SQL queries and show elapsed time. But we needed a way to show duration  like dd:hh:mm:ss:ms

Therefore i got the function from link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577898/sql-time-difference-between-two-dates-result-in-hhmmss) with code as below

```
--get the difference between two datetimes in the format: 'hh:mm:ss'
CREATE FUNCTION getDateDiff(@startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME)
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @seconds INT = DATEDIFF(s, @startDate, @endDate)
    DECLARE @difference VARCHAR(10) =
    FORMAT(@seconds / 3600, '00') + ':' +
    FORMAT(@seconds % 3600 / 60, '00') + ':' +
    FORMAT(@seconds % 60, '00')
    RETURN @difference
END
```

But cant get this to work if i need day and milliseconds as well.

How can i use above to display dd:hh:mm:ss:ms or return data in this format? And we have to make sure it works for SQL2012 and +

IF there is a better code out there please guide me as i am novice to SQL dev part, thanks

Edit- Getting -ve value in seconds as mentioned in comment

[image]

With the 2nd edit i am seeing issues with day now:

Please see below

for start time "5/21/2021 8:00:23 PM" (ET) and end date "5/22/2021 01:09:0 6 AM"

it returned me 1 5:9:17.13 which is incorrect as should not be 1 day and 5 hours rather should be 5 hours so something is going wrong on day

You can can see that value is completely incorrect
[image]

Comment: I'd love to know of a query that takes more than a day!

Comment: @Charlieface : Not really the workload queries but yes connections from sp_server_diagnostics and in case monitoring server running there would be trace related showing running let’s say since last reboot which I have seen is 30 days. Yes we can exclude such process but just in case wanted to know if one do not want to exclude them

Answer (score 1):

it calculate `datediff()` in `minute` because using `second` or `millisecond` will surely cause overflow when the date is far apart.

```
declare @date_start datetime    = '2021-05-01',
        @date_en    datetime    = getdate()


select  [@date_start]   = @date_start,
        [@date_en]  = @date_en,
        concat(dy, ':', hr, ':', mn, ':', sc, '.', ms)
from    (
        select  dy = abs(diff_mins / 60 / 24),
                hr = diff_mins / 60 % 24,
                mn = diff_mins % 60,
                sc = datediff(second, dateadd(minute, diff_mins, @date_start), @date_en),
                ms = (datepart(millisecond, @date_en) - datepart(millisecond, @date_start) + 1000) % 1000
        from    (
                    select  diff_mins = datediff(minute, @date_start, @date_en)
                ) d
        ) d
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8341eb4bedb0820cca802fc7200034b9)

You also need to increase the size of the return string `RETURNS VARCHAR(10)` as `dd:hh:mm:ss.mmm` is 15 characters

---

EDIT : to handle where `@date_start` is later than `@date_en`

Also added a `sg` to indicate when such case, the sign is `-`

```
declare @date_start datetime    = '2021-05-31',
        @date_en    datetime    = getdate()


select  [@date_start]   = @date_start,
        [@date_en]  = @date_en,
        concat(sg, dy, ':', hr, ':', mn, ':', sc, '.', ms)
from    (
        select  sg = case when @date_start > @date_en then '-' else '' end,
                dy = abs(datediff(day, @date_start, @date_en)),
                hr = abs(diff_mins / 60 % 24),
                mn = abs(diff_mins % 60),
                sc = abs(datediff(second, dateadd(minute, diff_mins, @date_start), @date_en)),
                ms = (datepart(millisecond, @date_en) - datepart(millisecond, @date_start) + 1000) % 1000
        from    (
                    select  diff_mins = datediff(minute, @date_start, @date_en)
                ) d
        ) d
```

Comment: @SQuirrel- Sorry i unmarked as answer as i ran into issues with above code. The seconds show up in (-) negative values. Example date_start in our case comes as input 2021-05-20 07:18:56:000. Will apprecitae if you can guide me how to fix (-ve) value coming in seconds

Comment: use `ABS()` on the values

Comment: Edited the answer with necessary changes

Comment: Thanks that very much helps. Some data still shows day in -ve. while hh mm ss and ms does not show that conflict

Comment: for `@date_start` is later than `@date_en` case, how do you want it ? Provide a sample data and expected result

Comment: @Squirell, i think time diff is fraction of seconds when start may be later than end date. I have to check why that could be the case. From your last edit everything looked good, its just sometimes day is returned as -0. so its like -0:3:43:23:234 rather it should be 0 3:43:23:234: Thank you again so for being prompt on your responses

Comment: it will be good if you can also provide the start and end date time that resulted in this

Comment: Just added the issue i am seeing where day is returned as 1 while its just been 5 hours. So something is not correct around day

Comment: Thank and appreciate you checking every time but still see-ve See below Start date
2021-05-31 00:00:00.000 end date-2021-05-24 21:46:09.377 difference  -7:2:14:9.376

Comment: When start date is later than end date, it will show as negative. If you only want the absolute value, remove the `sg` from the `concat`

Answer (score 0):

The function returns `varchar(10)`. The `dd:hh:mm:ss:ms` pattern is 14 characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you just output your two columns to SSRS, a *TimeSpan* can be used to get the difference between two *DateTime* values to great precision, but then... how to format it?  Apparently SSRS can't handle *TimeSpan*s directly in an expression, but the Code option **can**.  Therefore:

1. Put a function like this into your report's Code block ("ff" is for the fractions of a second):

```
Function FormatTimeSpan(ByVal TS as TimeSpan) AS String

DIM Minus AS String
IF TS < TimeSpan.Zero THEN
   Minus = "-"
ELSE
   Minus = ""
   END IF
IF ABS(TS.TotalSeconds) >= 86400 THEN
   Return Minus & TS.ToString("d' days 'h\:mm\:ss\.ff")
ELSE
   Return Minus & TS.ToString("h\:mm\:ss\.ff")
   END IF

End Function
```

2. Put something like the following in your expression.  In my case I wanted the elapsed time of computing the report.  You would want to substitute fields for Now() and Globals!ExeuctionTime:

```
="Time to execute: " & Code.FormatTimeSpan(Now().Subtract(Globals!ExecutionTime))
```

Also noteworthy... the format strings for *TimeSpan* are different from those for (.NET)*DateTime*:

[Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings)