# date time difference get hour:minutes:seconds

Tags: sql

I have query like this:

```
select t.Paydate,t.DelDate,DATEDIFF(MI, t.Paydate,t.DelDate) as Datdiffernce 
from Transaction_tbl t 
where t.transactID=19
```

I am getting out put like this:

```
Paydate                 DelDate                 Datdiffernce
----------------------- ----------------------- ------------
2013-05-07 18:36:50.000 2013-05-07 18:58:32.000     22
```

`Datedifference` am getting only 22 mints.

Instead of getting that how I can get date difference in this format `hh:mm:ss`?

Comment: you will need to use something like dateadd(s,datediff(s, t.paydate,t.deldate) as datedifference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx check out MSDN link

Comment: i want to get out like 0hr:22mnts:00seconds ,,is ther any way to get out put in thsi format

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating timespan with t-sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758891/calculating-timespan-with-t-sql)

Comment: @SachinShanbhag Please read the question properly before voting to close.

Comment: @fancyPants - Please explain how is this question different from the possible duplicate I have marked?

Comment: This question is not about how to calculate the timespan, he got this already by using timediff(), it's about representing minutes in hh:mm:ss format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT convert(varchar(10),DATEDIFF(hour,t.Paydate,t.DelDate))+'hr:' 
      +convert(varchar(10),DATEDIFF(minute,t.Paydate,t.DelDate)% 60) + 'mnts:' 
      +convert(varchar(10),DATEDIFF(SECOND,t.Paydate,t.DelDate)% 60) +'seconds'
       AS 'DIFF IN HH:MM:SS'
FROM Transaction_tbl t 
WHERE t.transactID=19
```

Comment: if @startdate='2013-10-01 15:05:17' and @enddate='2013-10-01 15:10:16' then the above code gives 5min:59seconds but the actual difference is 4min:59seconds

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @starttime datetime, @endtime datetime, @seconds int

Set @starttime ='2013-10-01 15:05:17'
Set @endtime = '2013-10-01 15:10:16'

set @seconds = DateDiff(second, @starttime, @endtime)
Select Convert(varchar(10), @seconds/3600) + 'hr:'
       +Convert(varchar(10), (@seconds % 3600)/60) + 'mnts:'
       +Convert(varchar(10), (@seconds % 3600) % 60) + 'seconds'
```

Reference: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758891/calculating-timespan-with-t-sql?lq=1)