# converting minutes to hour:minutes:second in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `transaction` like this:

```
transactID    Paydate                   DelDate                     vtid
24            2013-05-08 16:53:03.000   2013-05-08 17:00:28.000     8
25            2013-05-08 16:34:38.000   2013-05-08 17:00:14.000     7
```

I wrote the query like this for getting sum of date difference:

```
select 
    v.Vtype, 
    SUM(DATEDIFF(MI, t.Paydate, t.DelDate)) as sum_min,
    AVG(CONVERT(NUMERIC(18, 2), DATEDIFF(MI, t.Paydate, t.DelDate))) as avg_min
from 
    Transaction_tbl t 
left join 
    VType_tbl v on t.vtid = v.vtid 
where 
    t.transactID in (24, 25) 
group by 
    v.Vtype
```

I am getting proper output in minutes:

```
Vtype           sum_min     avg_min
----- ----------- ---------------------------------------
Normal             26          26.000000
VIP                7           7.000000
```

Instead of getting `sum_min` column in minutes I want to get output in `hh:mm:ss`. So my expected output should be like this:

```
Vtype           sum_min              avg_min
----- ----------- ---------------------------------------
Normal            00:26:00          26.000000
VIP                00:7:00           7.000000
```

For getting this I wrote the query like this:

```
 SELECT 
     convert(varchar(10), sum(DATEDIFF(hour, t.Paydate, t.DelDate))) + ':' +
     convert(varchar(10), sum(DATEDIFF(minute, t.Paydate, t.DelDate) % 60)) + ':' +
     convert(varchar(10), sum(DATEDIFF(SECOND, t.Paydate, t.DelDate) % 60)) AS 'HH:MM:SS'
FROM 
     Transaction_tbl t 
WHERE 
     t.transactID in (24, 25) 
group by 
     vtid
```

But in my output 1 hr is coming extra. While executing this query I am getting output like this:

```
 HH:MM:SS
--------------------------------
1:26:36
1:7:25
```

So how can I re-write my query for getting proper result?

Comment: `DATEDIFF(HOUR,...)` only looks at the hours; since `DelDate` has an hour of `17` and `PayDate` has an hour of `16`, you get back a value of `1`

Comment: that answer is wrong right????

Answer (score 0):

marc_s is right with his comment. What you need is a function like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7404565/447489).

You would then call it like this:

```
SELECT 
     udfTimeSpanFromSeconds(SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, t.Paydate, t.DelDate))) AS 'HH:MM:SS'
FROM 
     Transaction_tbl t 
WHERE 
     t.transactID in (24, 25) 
group by 
     vtid
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert minutes or seconds to `hh:mm:ss` format then you could use these functions (DATEADD,CONVERT with [style 114](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and LEFT):

```
DECLARE @PayDate     DATETIME,
        @DelDate     DATETIME,
        @DiffSeconds INT,
        @DiffMinutes INT;

SELECT  @PayDate='2013-05-08T16:53:03.000',
        @DelDate='2013-05-08T17:00:28.000',
        @DiffSeconds=DATEDIFF(SECOND,@PayDate,@DelDate),
        @DiffMinutes=DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@PayDate,@DelDate);


SELECT  @DiffSeconds AS Diff_Seconds,
        LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),DATEADD(SECOND,@DiffSeconds,0),114),8) AS Diff_From_Seconds,
        @DiffMinutes AS Diff_Minutes,
        LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),DATEADD(MINUTE,@DiffMinutes,0),114),8) AS Diff_From_Minutes;
```

Results:

```
Diff_Seconds Diff_From_Seconds Diff_Minutes Diff_From_Minutes
------------ ----------------- ------------ -----------------
445          00:07:25          7            00:07:00
```