# converting secondcolumn value(minutes) to hour:minutes:second using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have query like this:

First query:

```
SELECT* FROM Transaction_tbl WHERE Locid=6 AND Paydate is not null
```

Second query:

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(MI,t.Paydate,t.DelDate)) as Totalv , 
    AVG( CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2), DATEDIFF(MI,t.Paydate,t.DelDate))) as Average
FROM Transaction_tbl t 
WHERE Locid=6
```

my output:

```
Totalv | Average
-------+-----------
33169  | 1745.736842
```

But i want to get `average` in `hour:minutes:second`, is there any way to get average in hh:mm:ss format.

Comment: Duplicate of [converting minutes to hour:minutes:second in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770043/converting-minutes-to-hourminutessecond-in-sql?rq=1)?

Answer (score 0):

Not the easiest thing to do, but it's not rocket science.

What I did was get the averge seconds in the sub query, then div the seconds by 3600, which gets you hours 1).

To get the minutes 2), I subtract from the average seconds all the seconds accounted for in the hours.

Then 3), to get the leftover seconds, I added together all the seconds accounted for in the hours, all the seconds accounted for in the minutes and then subtracted those seconds from the average seconds, which gives you the leftover seconds.

The casting is necessary when you concat the numbers to text

```
select 
cast(AvgSec/3600 as varchar(2)) +':'                       --1) gets hours
+cast(AvgSec/60 -((AvgSec/3600) * 60) as varchar(2))  +':' --2) gets minutes
+cast((AvgSec - ((((AvgSec/3600) *60)*60)                  --3) leftover seconds 
+ ((AvgSec/60 -((AvgSec/3600) * 60))*60))) as varchar(2)) as 'hh:mm:ss' 
from (
    select avg(datediff(s,date1,date2)) as AvgSec
    from _dates
)as sub
```