# Time Addition in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two time value like

```
Time1=23:59:59:999
Time2=23:59:59:999
```

when i add up these two time (Time1+Time2) and i want result will be 47:59:58 rather than 23:59:58.

How can i do this? please suggest!!

Comment: please tag the version of sql server you are using

Comment: No sql server datatype can have value `47:59:58`. Character types can have value `'47:59:58'`. So do your datetime math and convert to varchar your own way.

Comment: 47:59:58 isn't a valid DateTime in SQL - what you are working with there is more like a timespan - unless there is a new SQL version with a timespan type in it, conventional wisdom seems to be to store seconds, milliseconds or ticks as a bigint and use conversion functions

Comment: Add times. That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: THe question is what are you trying to achieve with this? what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Do note that 47:59:98 isn't the correct outcome, that would be 47:59:59.998. If you represent your durations as milliseconds, adding them is simple, but formatting them appropriately in T-SQL is not. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/7404565/4137916 .

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at times and durations:

- A **datetime** is a moment in time, say June 28, 1978 at 15:23.
- A **time** without a datepart is a repetitive moment in time, e.g. "I get up every day at 7:00". (This is what you are using. But I get up at 8:00 and go to sleep at 23:00 doesn't make 8 + 23 = 31. It makes no sense to add times.)
- Then there is **timespan** (e.g. from 2016-01-01 3:00 to 2016-01-02 13:00).
- And then there is **duration** (e.g. six minutes). This is what you want to deal with.

You are storing a duration in a time, which is not really the appropriate data type. As SQL Server does not provide a special data type for a duration, you can use a numeric type for this and store seconds or microseconds or whatever you think appropriate. These you can easily add (provided both values have the same unit, e.g. microseconds).

As to displaying the duration you can write a function providing you with the format you like best for a duration (e.g. '913 days, 9 hours, 5 minutes, and 55.123 seconds').

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that is really hard in SQL Server.  How about `'1 23:59:58'`?  If so:

```
select cast(time1 as datetime) + time2
```

If you actually want the format in HH:MM:SS format, then you will need to do a lot of string manipulation.