# SQL - Operand data type datetime2 is invalid for subtract operator

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to subtract the value of the first row from the value of the second row of column `_timestamp` (shown below). `_number` is the ordering column in my data.

[image]

and put the result in a new column called **diff**. I have tried it with the following query

```
use dbtest

select 
    t2._number, t2._timestamp, 
    coalesce(t2._timestamp - (select t1._timestamp from dbo.tcp t1 
                              where t1._number = t2._number + 1), t2._timestamp) as diff
from 
    dbo.tbl t2
```

but I am getting the following error.

> Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
> Operand data type datetime2 is invalid for subtract operator.

Any tips would be appreciated. I have a huge record and I want to automatically apply it for the entire column.I am using SQL Sever 2008.

Comment: See datediff function https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: use datediff https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx  Do you need only two rows or all the records?

Comment: No, I want to apply it to all the records (around 300,000 rows)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can't subtract timestamps with `-` operator. Use `DATEDIFF` function instead.
To get the difference of the current row and the next row's timestamps, use `OUTER APPLY`.

```
select t2._number,t2._timestamp, 
datediff(microsecond,t2._timestamp,t1._timestamp) as diff
from dbo.tbl t2
outer apply (select t1._timestamp 
             from dbo.tcp t1
             where t1._number = t2._number + 1) t1
```

Edit: To `update` a column named diff per the OP's comment,

```
with cte as (          
select t2._number,t2._timestamp, t2.diff,
datediff(microsecond,t2._timestamp,t1._timestamp) as diff_col
from t t2
outer apply (select t1._timestamp 
             from t t1
             where t1._number = t2._number + 1) t1
   )
update cte set diff=diff_col;
```

Comment: do you mean updating the `diff` column with the results of the query above?

Comment: @DestaHaileselassieHagos .. see the edit..you can use a cte to update.

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed not feasible with the `datetime2`

```
DECLARE @t1 DATETIME2(7) = '2020-01-01 13:20:00.000'
DECLARE @t2 DATETIME2(7) = '2020-01-01 13:22:23.000'
 
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@t2 - @t1, 108)

>> Operand data type datetime2 is invalid for subtract operator.
```

But when converted to a `datetime`, it gives a nice result ;-)

```
DECLARE @t1 DATETIME2(7) = '2020-01-01 13:20:00.000' 
DECLARE @t2 DATETIME2(7) = '2020-01-01 13:22:23.000'

SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CONVERT(DATETIME, @t2) - CONVERT(DATETIME, @t1), 108)

>> 00:02:23
```