# Return result between Declared dates, possible optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here checking 2 columns to use search query by datetime (A and B cases).
Using declared dates for search filter in column:

A) `Entry_Timestamp`, and it is working how intended, but I think that bottom part with BETWEEN looks ugly. Is there any way to shorten or optimize code? Please provide examples.

B) `Received_Timestamp`, here it fails

**Notes**: `Entry_Timestamp` data is of type `datetime`, but column `Received_Timestamp` is `datetime2(2)`

**A) code:**

```
DECLARE @DateBeg DATETIME = '2018-12-01T04:00:00'
DECLARE @DateEnd DATETIME = '2018-12-01T05:59:59'

SELECT   
    dd.SN AS ID, 
    DATEADD(mi, dat.UtcOffset, DATEADD(ss, dat.ValueTime, '1970-01-01T00:00:00')) AS Entry_Timestamp,
    DATEADD(mi, dat.UtcOffset, dat.ReceivedTime) AS Received_Timestamp,
    val.Value
FROM    
    DataStore.AgregatedStorageData dat
CROSS APPLY 
    DataStore.fn_ConvertValueData(dat.ValueData, dat.ValueUnit, dat.ValueScaler) val
INNER JOIN 
    DataStore.dc_CaptureObjects co ON co.CaptureObjectID = dat.CaptureObjectID
                                   AND co.ClassId = 3
                                   AND co.LogicalName IN (0x0100011D00FF -- ActiveFilter
                                                         )
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.dm_Devices dd ON dat.DeviceId = dd.Id
WHERE   
    dat.ValueTime BETWEEN DATEDIFF(ss, '1970-01-01T00:00:00', @DateBeg - '02:00:00') AND 
                          DATEDIFF(ss, '1970-01-01T00:00:00', @DateEnd - '02:00:00')
```

Result:

[image]

**B) Code:**

```
DECLARE @DateBeg DATETIME2 = '2018-12-01T04:00:00'
DECLARE @DateEnd DATETIME2 = '2018-12-01T05:59:59'

SELECT
    dd.SN AS ID,
    DATEADD(mi, dat.UtcOffset, DATEADD(ss, dat.ValueTime, '1970-01-01T00:00:00')) AS Entry_Timestamp,
    DATEADD(mi, dat.UtcOffset, DATEADD(ss, dat.ReceivedTime, '1970-01-01T00:00:00')) AS Received_Timestamp,
    val.Value
FROM    
    DataStore.AgregatedStorageData dat
CROSS APPLY 
    DataStore.fn_ConvertValueData(dat.ValueData, dat.ValueUnit, dat.ValueScaler) val
INNER JOIN 
    DataStore.dc_CaptureObjects co ON co.CaptureObjectID = dat.CaptureObjectID
                                   AND co.ClassId = 3
                                   AND co.LogicalName IN (0x0100011D00FF -- ActiveFilter
                                                         )
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.dm_Devices dd ON dat.DeviceId = dd.Id
WHERE   
    dat.ReceivedTime BETWEEN DATEDIFF(ss, '1970-01-01T00:00:00', @DateBeg - '02:00:00')
                         AND DATEDIFF(ss, '1970-01-01T00:00:00', @DateEnd - '02:00:00')
```

I get an error

> Operand data type datetime2 is invalid for subtract operator. On line 21

[image]

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish would all help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff just ask questions. What you think from description is still missing. Point A) is provided working search query and a result in picture. Asking for possible query optimization;
B) search query searching in other column (datetime2) and desired result would be for starting to finish without error, after then similar what is in point A) picture. Just switched column where search is happening.

Comment: Duplicate of (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908098/sql-operand-data-type-datetime2-is-invalid-for-subtract-operator)

Comment: "Looks ugly"? Hardly a measure of T-SQL... beauty is in the eye of the beholder... does it work is more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Reason for the error

> Operand data type datetime2 is invalid for subtract operator. On line 21

The problem is when you subtract 2 hours from the "@DateBeg" and "@DateEnd" on BETWEEN clause.

You can try instead

```
WHERE   
dat.ReceivedTime BETWEEN DATEDIFF(ss, '1970-01-01T00:00:00', DATEADD(Hour,-2,@DateBeg) )
                     AND DATEDIFF(ss, '1970-01-01T00:00:00', DATEADD(Hour,-2,@DateEnd) )
```

Comment: The problem is that you cannot use subtract with datetime2. An alternative is to cast as datetime.

Comment: I did try for B) and now on line 5:
Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with int.