# DateDiff Function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I have a query

```
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(SS, DATEDIFF(SS, '2017/08/24 06:00', '2017/08/25 07:15'), 0), 114)
```

which gives output as **01:15:00**, where the date is not considered. My expected output is **25:15:00** because the difference of the day is 1. I tried with replacing SS with HH but did not get the desired help.

Comment: wht you want time diff ???

Comment: are you sure the diff would be 25:15:00 ??

Comment: Take a look at this question:(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758891/calculating-timespan-with-t-sql)

Comment: @YogeshSharma - Yes, I want time difference by considering date also.. In above case time diff is 25+ hours

Comment: have you try using cast (date1-date2 as time(0)) wht output it gives ?

Comment: It  return 1H because you have more than 24h, the problem not in datediff, it's on convert.

Comment: I tried this 'CONVERT(varchar(8), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(mi, '2017/08/24 06:00', '2017/08/25 07:15') * 1000, 0), 114)' - 25 shows as minutes

Answer (score 3):

```
with cte as
(
select DATEDIFF(SS, '2017/08/24 06:00', '2017/08/25 07:15') as ss
)

select cast (ss/3600 as varchar(10)) +':' + right( '00' +cast(ss % 3600 / 60 as varchar(2)), 2) + ':' + right( '00' + cast( (ss % 3600 )% 60 as varchar(2)), 2)
from cte
```

Comment: I like this answer more than the answers in the duplicate questions.